# Getting the length of a Dom object PHP

Tags: php, dom

I have this code:

```
    $strhtml = $segatieladvance;
    $dochtml = new DOMDocument();
    $dochtml->loadHTML($strhtml);
    $elm = $dochtml->getElementById('upPanelActuciones');
$segatiel= $dochtml->saveXml($elm);
```

I want to know the number of caracthers in $segatiel, how I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) function

`strlen($segatiel)`